# How do you charge a quirk special without activating it first

Tags: my-hero-ones-justice

When I try to charge my quirk specials with, say, Midoriya or Bakugo as explained in the tutorial by holding down the button for the action, the initial button press triggers the uncharged ability, and then I have to continue to hold it for the charge.  After the visual cue I can use the ability again for the full charged effect, but having to trigger the default ability before this charge is annoying and often causes me to expose myself.

I played against a Bakugo recently online who was visibly charging up his quirk specials without having to trigger them first.  How'd he do it?  I've also seen the AI do this in mission mode.

Playing on PS4 if it makes a difference, though it shouldn't.